# How to force Qt widgets to maintain equal height and width?

Tags: ruby, qt, qt4, qwidget, aspect-ratio

I'm using Ruby Qt bindings.

I'm trying to make a square widget (checker board), but it doesn't seem to work.
[This is the code that I tried](http://pastie.org/420860)

What is the proper way to making a widget that maintains its aspect ratio?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this question: [How to maintain widget's aspect ratio in Qt?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/452333/how-to-maintain-widgets-aspect-ratio-in-qt)

Comment: I've sub classed QGridLayout and implemented sizePolicy,hasHeightForWidth,heightForWidth(w)

I haven't implemented setGeometry, and this is my main suspect right now. As for the other functions listed there, I figured they were related to having a single item in the layout, is this correct?

Comment: I've implemented setGeometry and I can see the effect now... 
Now the layout and it's content aspect ratio is maintained but the aspect ratio of the main window isn't.

Comment: I haven't done it myself, but in that post is a lot of information. There are also some links to the Qt documentation.

Comment: I've just seen that there's a complete example at the first link.