# Forcing an Aspect Ratio when resizing a main window

Tags: qt

I understand that in Qt4, there is no single flag you can set to have the mouse driven resizing of the window maintain a certain aspect ratio (say, 1:1). Is there a way to force a new size for the window while in "resizeEvent (QResizeEvent * event)"? the parameters of the event don't seem to support change or give the user a chance to inject a new size.

My goal: GUI/Mouse resizing of a certain window will maintain its current aspect ratio, regardless of where you resize it from (sides, top, bottom, corners).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Duplicate Question?
[How to maintain widgets aspect ratio in Qt?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/452333/how-to-maintain-widgets-aspect-ratio-in-qt)

> Citing the answer by 'df' in the above link
>
> Calling resize() from within resizeEvent() has never worked well for
>   me -- at best it will cause flickering as the window is resized twice
>   (as you have), at worst an infinite loop.
>
> I think the "correct" way to maintain a fixed aspect ratio is to
>   create a custom layout. You'll have to override just two methods,
>   QLayoutItem::hasHeightForWidth() and QLayoutItem::heightForWidth().

Also checkout Sam Dutton's solution @ http://lists.trolltech.com/qt-interest/2007-01/msg00204.html

```
void MyWindow::resizeEvent(QResizeEvent * /*resizeEvent*/) 
{
    int containerWidth = _myContainerWidget->width();
    int containerHeight = _myContainerWidget->height();

    int contentsHeight = containerHeight ;
    int contentsWidth = containerHeight * _aspectRatio;
    if (contentsWidth > containerWidth ) {
        contentsWidth = containerWidth ;
        contentsHeight = containerWidth / _aspectRatio;
    }

    resizeContents(contentsWidth, contentsHeight);
}
```

Comment: not sure why I have to deal with Layout? I just need the main window frame to keep aspect ratio. The internal widgets are compatible with any size of the main frame as they stretch nicely when I free resize the frame

Answer (score 3):

Quoting a message in the thread [referenced by @blueskin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7259847/qt-forcing-an-aspect-ratio-when-resizing-a-main-window/7259953#7259953):

> This is surprisingly difficult to do. Most of the window systems do not
>   allow the application to set constraints on the window other than the
>   max and min sizes and that it can be fixed size.

The most common way to attempt this is to call resize from within the resize event.  This often causes recursion problems or looks strange because the widget resizes in ways the user has not requested.

Since most window systems do not allow the main window to be resized appropriately, the best solution is often to constrain a child widget rather than the parent. One such way to do this is with a class provided by libqxt.

[libqxt](http://libqxt.org) has support for keeping a child widget at a certain aspect ratio through its  [QxtLetterBoxWidget](http://libqxt.bitbucket.org/doc/tip/qxtletterboxwidget.html). @blueskin's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7259847/qt-forcing-an-aspect-ratio-when-resizing-a-main-window/7259953#7259953) provides one good attempt at doing what was originally requested.

If you're interested I'd recommend you read the [source](http://dev.libqxt.org/libqxt/src/69091033ff63/src/gui/qxtletterboxwidget.cpp) for the `resizeWidget()` function and observe the places in which it gets called. As background, libqxt uses the [pimpl](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opaque_pointer) idiom and `qxt_d()` gets at the private member.

Comment: Why child widgets? I need my main window to maintain aspect ration, all the internat widgets have size policy of stretch and work with any size. It's just getting to constrain the main frame to always keep its aspect ratio?

Comment: I've edited my answer to clarify why child widgets/layouts are usually used.

Answer (score 1):

Another quick and simpler way to do it:
http://developer.qt.nokia.com/forums/viewthread/5320/#31866

```
#include <QWidget>
#include <QApplication>
#include <QSizePolicy>

class MyWidget:public QWidget
{
public:
  MyWidget():QWidget(){};
  ~MyWidget(){};
  virtual int heightForWidth ( int w ) const { return w*9/16;};
};

int main (int argv, char** argc)
{
  QApplication a(argv,argc);
  MyWidget w;
  QSizePolicy qsp(QSizePolicy::Preferred,QSizePolicy::Preferred);
  qsp.setHeightForWidth(true);
  w.setSizePolicy(qsp);
  w.show();

  a.exec();
}
```

Comment: I took the code as is, tried to run it under Mac OSX and Qt 4.7.3 -- no effect. Window resizes freely without any constraints

Comment: heightForWidth is not used by top level widgets, only layout managers.