# How to maintain specific height to width ratio of widget in qt5?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

I tried overriding methods hasHeightToWidth() and heightToWidth() but it didn't work for some reason.
Is there some complete example that I can use?

**Upd1:**

```
class MyWidget : public QWidget {
    Q_OBJECT

public: 
    MyWidget() {
        QSizePolicy sizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Preferred, QSizePolicy::Preferred);
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(true);
        setSizePolicy(sizePolicy);
    }
    bool hasHeightForWidth() const override {
        std::cout << __FUNCTION__ << std::endl;
        return true;
    }
    int heightForWidth(int w) const override {
        std::cout << __FUNCTION__ << " " << w << std::endl;
        return w;
    }
    QSize sizeHint() const override {
        return QSize(100, heightForWidth(100));
    }
};
```

MyWidget instances are inserted in QHBoxLayout.

I use qt5.

Debug std::cout's show that hasHeightForWidth and heightForWidth are called many times

Comment: See this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/452333/how-to-maintain-widgets-aspect-ratio-in-qt

Comment: And possibly this one: http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/5320

Comment: @Phlucious, I saw both pages, I did as written there (overrided hasHeightToWidth and heightToWidth)

Comment: Have you also changed the sizePolicy for your widget like [this guy suggests](http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/5320/#31866)?

Comment: @Phlucious, yes, I did. Added code to question.