# Resizing Qt Widgets based on Window size

Tags: qt, qwidget, qsizepolicy

I have certain Qt widgets inserted into QLayouts that are children of a Qt Window. I am trying to add a suggested size that the widgets need to be initialized with. I would also like Qt to resize the widgets proportional to what the Qt Window was resized. Additionally I would like to set an aspect ratio to the widgets that must be honored. However, the only way I can do so is using setFixedSize(). Though this widget cannot be rescaled with the window. Any suggestions??

EDIT: I tried inheriting QWidget and reimplementing heightForWidth(int w) function as described here ([How to maintain widgets aspect ratio in Qt?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/452333/how-to-maintain-widgets-aspect-ratio-in-qt))!  . Did not have any luck with that. I am setting the layout within a QtScrollArea derived class.

Comment: Well, I can only tell you that these things are possible to do using layouts. No one can help you since you have provided no code and no strict requirements about what you want to do.