# Resizing child widget with keeping aspect ratio when parent widget resized

Tags: qt, qt4, qwidget, qt4.8

I have four widgets in a `QWidgets` named `FourWindowWidget` I am trying to put these four widgets in FourWindowWidget as one at top and remaining under that while the top one should always have 70% of the size of FourWindowWidget. I tried following :

```
QSize size = ui->FourWindowWidget->size();

ui->View1->setFixedHeight(size.height()*0.70);

QHBoxLayout * lay = new QHBoxLayout();
lay->addWidget(ui->View2);
lay->addWidget(ui->View3);
lay->addWidget(ui->View4);
lay->setMargin(0);
lay->setContentsMargins(0,0,0,0);

QGridLayout * mainlay =  new QGridLayout;
mainlay->addWidget(ui->View1,0,0);
mainlay->setContentsMargins(0,0,0,0);
mainlay->setHorizontalSpacing(0);
mainlay->setSpacing(0);
mainlay->setMargin(0);
mainlay->addLayout(lay,1,0);

delete ui->FourWindowWidget->layout();
ui->FourWindowWidget->setLayout(mainlay);
this->update();
```

Now the problem is now View1 have fixed size but size of FourWindowWidget is not fixed. It changes when I remove any other widget around it like closing dock widget. This resize is expected, or say I don't want to make it fixed. So when ever FourWindowWidget get resized its child widgets should be as per ratio set. But I am unable to do this cause 
1. There is no any signal that inform resize so the height of internal widget will be calculated. 
2. No other way I found to set 70% height of top widget rather than setFixedHeight in grid layout.

I have tried with setting QSizePolicy to setHieghtForWidth but iit is not a working solution. 
Please suggest me to do this by any way.

---

The Question is kind of duplicat of [Resizing Qt Widgets based on Window size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17013984/resizing-qt-widgets-based-on-window-size) but there nobody answered.

Comment: Did you try `setColumnStretch` / `setRowStretch` methods for your layouts?

Comment: @DmitrySazonov I tried it is not working.

Comment: Please, provide code sample, where you did it. Size policy of child widgets should not be fixed.

Comment: `1. There is no any signal that inform resize so the height of internal widget will be calculated` - There is [QWidget::resizeEvent](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtwidgets/qwidget.html#resizeEvent).

Comment: You don't need to handle resize events. Layouts will do all necessary work for you.

Comment: Try this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/452333/how-to-maintain-widgets-aspect-ratio-in-qt

Comment: @DmitrySazonov I'm not saying he should, I'm just pointing out that there is such a possibility. Setting stretch for the layout should work in this case, and would be the best solution.

Comment: Sorry, I thought that this message is from question author. Voted up your unswer, because it full answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting the stretch factor for your layout should work. I'm not sure why you are using a grid layout for this, when you are adding everything in the same column, but here is an example that works:

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    gridLayout = new QGridLayout;
    this->centralWidget()->setLayout(gridLayout);
    label1 = new QLabel("l1");
    label2 = new QLabel("l2");
    label3 = new QLabel("l3");
    label4 = new QLabel("l4");
    gridLayout->addWidget(label1, 0, 0);
    gridLayout->addWidget(label2, 1, 0);
    gridLayout->addWidget(label3, 2, 0);
    gridLayout->addWidget(label4, 3, 0);
    gridLayout->setRowStretch(0,7);
    gridLayout->setRowStretch(1,1);
    gridLayout->setRowStretch(2,1);
    gridLayout->setRowStretch(3,1);
}
```

In this example `label1` will take 70% of the available vertical space, while the other labels will take combined 30% of the available vertical space.

Comment: I was just setting 1 for 0th row and that was not appropriate parameter to get 70% you have explained it. thanks.

Comment: @Tab If you have trouble with layouts in the future, [this example](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/layouts-basiclayouts.html) might be able to help you out.