# QWidget::heightForWidth() and QMainWindow

Tags: c++, qt

In a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17708449/492336), I was given code which shows a implementation of `heightForWidth()` (thanks, @Kuba Ober) that works, but it does so only for a top-level `QWidget`. I tried to reproduce it for a `QMainWindow`, but it did not work.

This is the code where `heightForWidth()` works for a top-level `QWidget`:

```
QWidget w;
QVBoxLayout * l = new QVBoxLayout(&w);
l->addWidget(new Widget);
w.show();
```

And this is where I try to implement the same for QMainWindow, but here it `heightForWidth()` has no effect (even though it gets called):

```
QMainWindow mainWnd;
QWidget *w = new QWidget;
QVBoxLayout * l = new QVBoxLayout(w);
l->addWidget(new Widget);
mainWnd.setCentralWidget(w);
// Second widget to take unused space.
QFrame * btm = new QFrame;
btm->setFrameShape(QFrame::Panel);
btm->setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Expanding, QSizePolicy::Expanding);
l->addWidget(btm);
mainWnd.show();
```

So why doesn't the `QMainWindow` implementation work?

Comment: 1. When you add a central widget, it's redundant to set its parent. Docs say: *QMainWindow takes ownership of the widget pointer and deletes it at the appropriate time.*

Comment: 2. If a `QObject` will have its parent set at *any time*, either upon creation or later, it must be allocated on the free store. This is probably just a typo in the example code, but I wanted to stress that.

Comment: I think part of the problem is that `heightForWidth()` is meant to be a trade-off-mechanism, where you trade one for the other. When `width()` grows, height must not increase. If it happens to work with simple layouts, more win for you, but I don't think it's really meant to be used in such a way. Qt itself *always* uses it such that as you increase the width, height never increases. It either stays put or decreases. Think of a menubar or other wrapped text.

Comment: At the moment it looks to me that getting it "working" the way you intend it to work may require patching QMainWindowLayout, although I'm not completely sure yet.

Comment: I changed the my code, is it correct now with regards to 1) and 2)?

Comment: Btw, to give some context, I was trying to create a 'square' widget for a sudoku game, that can grow/shrink when you resize the window, but always stays square. I don't need it to affect the actual top-level window, so long as the widget itself always stays square. May be I should just ask that in a separate question, something like "How do I make a square widget in Qt".

Comment: Square widget implies `heightForWidth()`, so you're stuck there :)

Answer (score 0):

First note that a `QMainWindow` requires *something* to be set as the central widget, even if it's a placeholder.

All you need to do, then, is to have a placeholder widget with a layout in it, like you already do, and only then put *two* widgets inside: the one you want to stay square, plus a placeholder to pick up unused space.

Alternatively, why are you insisting on the *widget* being square? Just paint the square section inside, and clear the rest with default background role.

Comment: I tried adding a `QFrame` as a second widget, like in your code in the previous answer (see my edit), but it doesn't seem to change anything - the 'square' widget still takes all the available space of the `QMainWindow`. As for wanting a square widget, I thought that this is the more correct way to do it. The other solution is a bit hackish, I don't think a widget should have unused area. May be I can use a custom layout instead?

Comment: If you literally put the entire container widget from the other answer into the centralwidget, it shouldn't change the behavior of what's inside. If it does, it's a bug.

Comment: OK, I just tested it, I put the top-level QWidget from the previous answer as the central widget of a QMainWindow, and it's not working, while if I show it as a top-level widget, it works.

Comment: I'd suggest reporting it as a Qt bug. By not working I presume that the bottom QFrame does not appear?