# installing event filters in QT

Tags: qt, events

I am trying to avoid wasting time doing something if my lack of knowledge of QT could avoid me even to try.

Supposed a have a class X not derived from QGraphicsItems with fields containing among others several QGraphicsItems. Can I define event filters in X and install them on the QGraphicsItems in order to let X receive the event before the QGraphicsItems themselves?
Thanks.

Comment: In function `QObject::installEventFilter(QObject *)` both argument and class should be `QObject`s, but `QGraphicsItem` is not a QObject. I don't know what you X class is. Therefore, I think it is not possible.

Comment: Sure, but you want to install the event filter on the object that actually receives the events. In Qt, such objects must derive from `QObject`. Thus you need to filter events reaching `QGraphicsScene`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your design allows, rather than objects inheriting from QGraphicsItem, inherit from [QGraphicsObject](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qgraphicsobject.html), which will allow you to use the standard QObject::installEventFilter.

Otherwise, you would need to have class 'X' inherit from QGraphicsItem.

Then, you can install an event filter from one GraphicsItem to another through the QGraphicsScene. This is detailed in [the Qt Documentation here](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qgraphicsitem.html#installSceneEventFilter).

> *To filter another item's events, install this item as an event filter for the other item.*

Example:

```
 QGraphicsScene scene;
 QGraphicsEllipseItem *ellipse = scene.addEllipse(QRectF(-10, -10, 20, 20));
 QGraphicsLineItem *line = scene.addLine(QLineF(-10, -10, 20, 20));

 line->installSceneEventFilter(ellipse);
 // line's events are filtered by ellipse's sceneEventFilter() function.

 ellipse->installSceneEventFilter(line);
 // ellipse's events are filtered by line's sceneEventFilter() function.
```

Comment: Thanks. It makes my life more complicated. I am basically needed a class with QGraphicsItems and few non QT parameters, where the main QGraphicsItem can hide or shoe the rest when the mouse hovers on it.