# Qt layouts - Keep widget aspect ratio while resizing

Tags: c++, qt, layout, aspect-ratio

I want to keep an aspect ratio of 16/9 on a QGroupBox (the one on the left on the screenshot below). For the tests I made a simple program with 4 groupboxes in a vertical layout, all in an horizontal layout:

[image]
**main.cpp**

```
#include "MainWindow.h"
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

**MainWindow.h**

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();


private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

**MainWindow.cpp**

```
#include "MainWindow.h"
#include "ui_MainWindow.h"

#include <QDebug>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    qDebug() << "horizontalLayout->hasHeightForWidth: " << ui->horizontalLayout->hasHeightForWidth();
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

**MainWindow.ui**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>MainWindow</class>
 <widget class="QMainWindow" name="MainWindow">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>1000</width>
    <height>703</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>MainWindow</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="centralWidget">
   <layout class="QHBoxLayout" name="horizontalLayout">
    <item>
     <widget class="GroupBoxHFW" name="groupBox_1">
      <property name="title">
       <string>GroupBox</string>
      </property>
     </widget>
    </item>
    <item>
     <layout class="QVBoxLayout" name="verticalLayout">
      <item>
       <widget class="QGroupBox" name="groupBox_2">
        <property name="minimumSize">
         <size>
          <width>485</width>
          <height>204</height>
         </size>
        </property>
        <property name="maximumSize">
         <size>
          <width>485</width>
          <height>204</height>
         </size>
        </property>
        <property name="title">
         <string>GroupBox</string>
        </property>
       </widget>
      </item>
      <item>
       <widget class="QGroupBox" name="groupBox_3">
        <property name="minimumSize">
         <size>
          <width>485</width>
          <height>204</height>
         </size>
        </property>
        <property name="maximumSize">
         <size>
          <width>485</width>
          <height>204</height>
         </size>
        </property>
        <property name="title">
         <string>GroupBox</string>
        </property>
       </widget>
      </item>
      <item>
       <widget class="QGroupBox" name="groupBox_4">
        <property name="minimumSize">
         <size>
          <width>485</width>
          <height>204</height>
         </size>
        </property>
        <property name="maximumSize">
         <size>
          <width>485</width>
          <height>204</height>
         </size>
        </property>
        <property name="title">
         <string>GroupBox</string>
        </property>
       </widget>
      </item>
      <item>
       <spacer name="verticalSpacer">
        <property name="orientation">
         <enum>Qt::Vertical</enum>
        </property>
        <property name="sizeHint" stdset="0">
         <size>
          <width>20</width>
          <height>40</height>
         </size>
        </property>
       </spacer>
      </item>
     </layout>
    </item>
   </layout>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QMenuBar" name="menuBar">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>0</x>
     <y>0</y>
     <width>1000</width>
     <height>21</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QToolBar" name="toolBar">
   <property name="windowTitle">
    <string>toolBar</string>
   </property>
   <attribute name="toolBarArea">
    <enum>TopToolBarArea</enum>
   </attribute>
   <attribute name="toolBarBreak">
    <bool>false</bool>
   </attribute>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QStatusBar" name="statusBar"/>
 </widget>
 <layoutdefault spacing="6" margin="11"/>
 <customwidgets>
  <customwidget>
   <class>GroupBoxHFW</class>
   <extends>QGroupBox</extends>
   <header>GroupBoxHFW.h</header>
   <container>1</container>
  </customwidget>
 </customwidgets>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

**GroupBoxHFW.h**

```
#ifndef GROUPBOXHFW_H
#define GROUPBOXHFW_H

#include <QGroupBox>

class GroupBoxHFW : public QGroupBox
{
public:
    GroupBoxHFW(QWidget * parent = 0);
    GroupBoxHFW(const QString & title, QWidget * parent = 0);

    int heightForWidth(int w) const;
    bool hasHeightForWidth() const;
};

#endif // GROUPBOXHFW_H
```

**GroupBoxHFW.cpp**

```
#include "GroupBoxHFW.h"

#include <QDebug>

GroupBoxHFW::GroupBoxHFW(QWidget * parent) : QGroupBox(parent)
{
    QSizePolicy policy(this->sizePolicy());
    policy.setHeightForWidth(true);

    this->setSizePolicy(policy);
}

GroupBoxHFW::GroupBoxHFW(const QString & title, QWidget * parent) : QGroupBox(title, parent)
{
    QSizePolicy policy(this->sizePolicy());
    policy.setHeightForWidth(true);

    this->setSizePolicy(policy);
}


int GroupBoxHFW::heightForWidth(int w) const
{
    qDebug() << "GroupBoxHFW::heightForWidth called";
    return 9.f / 16.f * w;
}

bool GroupBoxHFW::hasHeightForWidth() const
{
    qDebug() << "GroupBoxHFW::hasHeightForWidth called";
    return true;
}
```

As you can see, I reimplemented the virtual functions `int heightForWidth(int w) const` and `bool hasHeightForWidth() const`, hoping my QGroupBox would resize automatically to a 16/9 aspect ratio. Unfortunately, it doesn't work. `GroupBoxHFW::heightForWidth()` is called only once when the program starts and it doesn't even resize the widget.

Here is the output of the program:

```
GroupBoxHFW::hasHeightForWidth called
horizontalLayout->hasHeightForWidth:  true
GroupBoxHFW::hasHeightForWidth called
GroupBoxHFW::heightForWidth called
GroupBoxHFW::hasHeightForWidth called
GroupBoxHFW::hasHeightForWidth called
GroupBoxHFW::hasHeightForWidth called
GroupBoxHFW::hasHeightForWidth called
```

What's even weirder is that none of the functions above (`hasHeightForWidth()` and `heightForWidth()` get called when I resize the window, while the QGroupBox is resized.

What's wrong?

Comment: In [How to maintain widgets aspect ratio in Qt?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/452333/how-to-maintain-widgets-aspect-ratio-in-qt) it was mentioned that subsclassing `QLayout`and overwriting the heightforwidth methods is the better approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your approach could work if this group box was inside vertical layout.

As name says `hasHeightForWidth` is well defined when height depends on width (this was designed for text wrapping), not another way around (your case).

What you can do? Try this (I've implemented something similar for `QGraphicsWidget` and it was working quite well):

```
QSize GroupBoxHFW::sizeHint() const {
    QSize s = size();
    lastHeight = s.height();
    s.setWidth((s.height()*16)/9);
    s.setHeight(QGroupBox::sizeHint().height());
    return s;
}

void GroupBoxHFW::resizeEvent(QResizeEvent * event) {
    QGroupBox::resizeEvent(event);

    if (lastHeight!=height()) {
        updateGeometry(); // it is possible that this call should be scheduled to next iteration of event loop
    }
}
```

**Small off topic:**
If I would do that I would try implement this functionality by subclass a `QLayout` and not as a subclass of some `QWidget`. This way this it could be used multiple times for different widgets.

Comment: It doesn't work either.
Note: you forgot that `sizeHint()` is const, you can't assign a member variable (`lastHeight`) inside this function. I removed the condition in `resizeEvent()` to fix the problem.

Comment: add keyword `mutable` for this field. Condition in `resizeEvent` is a must, to prevent infinite loop.