# How to resize child QLabel (having a QPixmap) with QHBLayout keeping aspect ratio?

Tags: image, qt, resize, qlabel

I am dynamically creating a `QLabel` named `label` (that has a `QPixmap`) inside a `QHBLayout` named `layout` inside a parent `QWidget` named by `this` such that the `QLabel` image resizes with parent `this` but maintains the original image aspect ratio.

What I am doing now is the following:

```
QHBoxLayout* layout = new QHBoxLayout(this);
label = new QLabel(str, this); /* This Label is my concern */
label->setAlignment(Qt::AlignLeft|Qt::AlignVCenter);
layout->addWidget(label);
layout->setAlignment(Qt::AlignCenter);
this->setLayout(layout);
layout->setContentsMargins(0,0,0,0);
layout->setSpacing(0);
label->setScaledContents(true);
label->setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Expanding, QSizePolicy::Expanding);
```

After searching online and as suggested in the accepted answer in [Qt layouts - Keep widget aspect ratio while resizing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24264320/qt-layouts-keep-widget-aspect-ratio-while-resizing), I even tried creating my own `MyLabel` class and defining `sizeHint()` and `resizeEvent(QResizeEvent* event)` as follows:

```
QSize MyLabel::sizeHint() const
{
    QSize s = size();
    lastHeight = s.height();
    lastWidth = s.width();
    QSize qs = QLabel::sizeHint();
    float ratio = std::min(((float)qs.width())/lastWidth, ((float)qs.height())/lastHeight);
    s.setWidth(lastWidth*ratio);
    s.setHeight(lastHeight*ratio);
    return s;
}

void MyLabel::resizeEvent(QResizeEvent* event)
{
    QLabel::resizeEvent(event);
    if(lastHeight!=height())
    {
        updateGeometry();
    }
}
```

But the `label` image still resizes without maintaining aspect ratio.

What am I missing here?

Any help will be highly appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Qt: resizing a QLabel containing a QPixmap while keeping its aspect ratio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8211982/qt-resizing-a-qlabel-containing-a-qpixmap-while-keeping-its-aspect-ratio)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the subclass of QLabel listed here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/22618496/999943

Hope that helps.

Comment: This class works. On comparing my defined `MyLabel` and this `AspectRatioPixmapLabel` class, it turns out that the main culprit is the use of the function call as `setScaledContents(true);`. It must be set as `setScaledContents(false);`. So I am proposing to update your helpful answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try to resize your image instead of `QLabel`. E.g. by hangling parent widget's resizeEvent and doing something like:

```
const QPixmap* pixmap = label->pixmap();
if (pixmap->width() >= newGeometry.width())
{
    QPixmap scaledPixmap = pixmap->scaledToWidth(newWidth, Qt::SmoothTransformation);
    label->setPixmap(scaledPixmap);
}
```