# Lock app orientation to landscape in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, qt4.8

I would like to lock my app  developed with Qt to landscape orientation, even if the screen display is portrait. I have tried adding to my code the resizeEvent method found here: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/widgets-orientation.html, but my app still does not display correctly. Here is my code for resizeEvent:

```
void MainWindow::resizeEvent(QResizeEvent *event)
{
    QSize size = event->size();
    qDebug() << size;
    bool isLandscape = size.width() > size.height();

    if (isLandscape == false){
        size.transpose();
    }

    this->setFixedSize(size);
}
```

Does anyone know how to do this in Qt 4.8.5? I am trying to display an app for a 320x240 display.

Thanks

Comment: I dont know for sure, but could it be that after setting the size to fixed, you dont get any further `resizeEvent`? The main difference between your approach and the example is, that you set the fixed size of the mainwindow instead of a (child)widget.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't really follow that example. It shows two different widgets depending on the orientation. Furthermore the doc warns about modifying size properties inside `resizeEvent`.

One solution would be to set a fix aspect ratio similar to `320x240` by overloading [QWidget::heightForWidth](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#heightForWidth). You wouldn't need to overload `resizeEvent`.

It will look like

```
int MainWindow::heightForWidth( int w ) { 
     return (w * 240 )/320; 
}
```

`heightForWidth` is discussed in detail in https://stackoverflow.com/a/1160476/1122645.

**edit:**

`sizeHint` is used by the ***layout of the parent*** to compute the size of children widgets. In general, it make sense to implement it as

```
QSize MainWindow::sizeHint() const
{
    int w = //some width you seem fit
    return QSize( w, heightForWidth(w) );
}
```

but if `MainWindow` is top level then it will not change anything. You can also [alter heightForWidth flag of your current size policy](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qsizepolicy.html#hasHeightForWidth)

```
QSizePolicy currPolicy = this->sizePolicy();
currPolicy->setHeightForWidth(true);
this->SetSizePolicy(currPolicy);
```

But again, if it is a top level widget I doesnt change much.

**Anyway you don't need to call `updateGeometry`.**

Comment: Hello, aside from heightForWidth, do I need also need to overload sizeHint()? Based from this link:http://doc.qt.digia.com/qq/qq04-height-for-width.html, I would also need to call updateGeometry as well, am I correct?

Comment: Thanks for clarifying,  it seems using sizeHint only applies for widgets inside layouts and not for top level windows like the one for my project. Either I can use heightForWidth and sizeHint on centralWidget or I can use setFixedSize() on the top level MainWindow.